# Not able to retrieve the spreadsheet id from workspace add-on

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

I'm developing a workspace add-on with alternate runtime; I configured the add-on to work with spreadsheets and I need to retrieve the spreadsheet id when the user opens the add-on. For test purposes I created a cloud function that contains the business logic.

My deployment.json file is the following:

```
{
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "My Spreadsheet Add-on",
      "logoUrl": "https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2070/PNG/512/penguin_icon_126624.png"
    },
    "sheets": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "cloudFunctionUrl"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, the request I receive seems to be empty and without the id of the spreadsheet in which I am, while I was expecting to have the spreadsheet id as per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/editors/gsao/building-editor-interfaces)

Is there anything else I need to configure?

The relevant code is quite easy, I'm just printing the request:

```
exports.getSpreadsheetId = function addonsHomePage (req, res) { console.log('called', req.method); console.log('body', req.body); res.send(createAction()); };
```

the information showed in the log is:

```
sheets: {}
```

Thank you

**UPDATE** It's a known issue of the engineering team, [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197081364) you can find the ticket

Comment: [Does this page help?](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes)

Comment: unfortunately that page is exactly what I followed and did

Comment: Can you share any relevant code? How do you handle the request?

Comment: sure, currently I just want to print the info in a log so the code is quite easy. I don't copy the manifest because I already put it in the question :)

exports.getSpreadsheetId = function addonsHomePage (req, res) {  
  console.log('called', req.method);
  console.log('body', req.body);
  res.send(createAction());
};

and in the logs I have

sheets: {} 

thank you

Comment: Can you update your question rather than putting it as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

The information around Workspace Add-ons is pretty new and the documentation is pretty sparse.

In case anyone else comes across this issue ... I solved it in python using CloudRun by creating a button that checks for for the object then if there is no object it  requests access to the sheet in question.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])    
def test_addon_homepage():
       req_body = request.get_json()
       sheet_info = req_body.get('sheets')
       card = {
            "action": {
                "navigations": [
                    {
                        "pushCard": {
                            "sections": [
                                {
                                    "widgets": [
                                        {
                                            "textParagraph": {
                                                "text": f"Hello {sheet_info.get('title','Auth Needed')}!"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
       if not sheet_info:
          card = create_file_auth_button(card)
    
       return card
    
    def create_file_auth_button(self, card):
         card['action']['navigations'][0]['pushCard']['fixedFooter'] = {
                'primaryButton': {
                    'text': 'Authorize file access',
                    'onClick': {
                        'action': {
                            'function': 'https://example-cloudrun.a.run.app/authorize_sheet'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          return card
    
    @app.route('/authorize_sheet', methods=['POST'])
    def authorize_sheet():
        payload = {
            'renderActions': {
                'hostAppAction': {
                    'editorAction': {
                        'requestFileScopeForActiveDocument': {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return payload
```